# Why can't I use a param called "action"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is "action" as a input field name forbidden? Because everything works except the assignment of the "action" param.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

because `action`, `controller` are prohibited words.

Look around `debug params`

```
--- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
action: index
controller: main
```

so you can't use those params. Because they will be REWRITED AUTOMATICALLY

Comment: If it's a POST request, here's the way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207671/rails-action-params-key-conflict

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest NOT using words like action, name, method as field names as they are all attributes of the form tag and are likely to get confused when the form is posted

Answer (score 2):

I agree with jbeynon, I would also say anything that has to do with CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) is protected also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this would be invalid. You'd want to avoid conflicting with existing class or method names (e.g. not a good idea to define a method called `action` on a controller).

> everything works except the assignment
>   of the "action" param.

Does this generate an error? If so, what exactly?