# How to get params value in action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have view

```
<%= form_tag('filter_ebook', :method => :post, :remote => true) do %>
  Filter By: <%= select_tag "action", options_for_select(search_price),:onchange => "this.form.submit();" -%>
<%end%>
```

Routes

```
resources :ebooks do
collection do
  get 'search'
  post 'filter_ebook'
end
end
```

I have applied on action on change of dropbox, but when I have saw param in action there is no value of selected value of dropbox.

I got `{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wnsNDzco60UdjEfOggtmnGCxhY1rzyVSm4WCCdt12Fs=", "action"=>"filter_ebook", "controller"=>"ebooks"}`

But I want selected value in action how can I get it?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use a parameter named `action`. It may conflict with Rails. Try with another name. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671732/why-cant-i-use-a-param-called-action

Comment: Also, when inside a form_tag, you have a reference back to the form passed to your block and you can use that to make the select with `<%= f.select, options_for_select %>` (etc)

Answer (score 0):

"action" is always the name of the controller's action - the one that is provided by the route, in your case "filter_ebook".

Just give your parameter a different name, like "action_type"