# How to make params[:action] work if I pass parameters "action=test" in the end of url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below is my index action:

```
def index
  @api = Api.find_by(name: params[:name])
  @descriptions = @api.descriptions.all

  if valid_json?(@descriptions.first.value)
  render json: JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(@descriptions.first.value))  
else
  flash[:danger] = "Something wrong with your JSON data."
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

end

when I use url "http://localhost:3000/xxxxxxxx?name=1234567890"
It will return data in JSON format.

However, if I change params[:name] to params[:action] and url to "http://localhost:3000/xxxxxxxx?action=1234567890", then it will not work anymore.

I know it is because params[:action] is equal index in this case, but is there any way I can still pass params[:action]=12345 or whatever I use in url?

Comment: In params rails passes 'action' and 'controller' parameter which clash with ur parameter. try different name than 'action'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671732/why-cant-i-use-a-param-called-action).

`action`, `controller` are [prohibited words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html). You should not use it in your params.

Comment: If it's a POST request, here's the way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207671/rails-action-params-key-conflict